# Create a user menu by getting the first two element in a 2 dimensional array using python

Tags: python

I am new to python programming, I the spent over 3 days trying to code this section and really getting me crazy. Would greatly appreciate if anyone could help me with the coding?

I have to create a this submenu selection with the below 2-D array. The menu has to be in the following format:

1. Apple Mac Book Air
2. Acer Aspire SW5-111
3. Asus MeMo Pad 7
4. Samsung Tab S8.4
5. Apple iPhone 7
6. Samsung Galaxy S8

Enter M to return to Main Menu
Else please enter your selection

Code

```
def main_menu(): 
    listOfProducts = [["Mac Book Air","Apple","Laptop","Equipped with the new fifth-generation Intel Core i5 and i7 processors with Intel HD Graphics.",1350.5],
            ["Aspire SW5-111", "Acer", "Laptop", "Intel® Atom Z3745 processor Quad-core 1.33 GHz CPU.", 510],
            ["MeMo Pad 7", "Asus", "Tablet", "The 7 inch ASUS MeMO Pad 7 was created for those looking for a value tablet.", 620],
            ["Tab S8.4", "Samsung", "Tablet", "You will be surprised by the slim and sleek design of the GALAXY Tab S (8.4\") LTE. It only weighs 298g (LTE) and is easy to carry anywhere.", 788.5],
            ["iPhone 7", "Apple", "Phone", "The iPhone 7 is an exceptional phone in nearly every way.", 900],
            ["Galaxy S8", "Samsung", "Phone", "Newly released!", 1000]]
```

Comment: Format your codesnippet

Answer (score 1):

```
for i, product in enumerate(listOfProducts):
    print('%s. %s %s' % (i+1, product[1], product[0]))
```

The `enumerate()` function in python returns a list of tuples containing the item index, and the item in the list. i.e. the enumerate function above returns:

```
[(0,["Mac Book Air".....])
```

...all the way down to:

```
(5,["Galaxy s8",...1000])]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

product_list = [
    ["Mac Book Air","Apple","Laptop","Equipped with the new fifth-generation Intel Core i5 and i7 processors with Intel HD Graphics.",1350.5],
    ["Aspire SW5-111", "Acer", "Laptop", "Intel® Atom Z3745 processor Quad-core 1.33 GHz CPU.", 510],
    ["MeMo Pad 7", "Asus", "Tablet", "The 7 inch ASUS MeMO Pad 7 was created for those looking for a value tablet.", 620],
    ["Tab S8.4", "Samsung", "Tablet", "You will be surprised by the slim and sleek design of the GALAXY Tab S (8.4\") LTE. It only weighs 298g (LTE) and is easy to carry anywhere.", 788.5],
    ["iPhone 7", "Apple", "Phone", "The iPhone 7 is an exceptional phone in nearly every way.", 900],
    ["Galaxy S8", "Samsung", "Phone", "Newly released!", 1000]
]

# Loop until user says "exit"
while True:
    # Print list of options
    for product_index in range(len(product_list)):
        print "%x: %s %s" % (product_index, product_list[product_index][1], product_list[product_index][0])

    # Read keyboard input from user
    chosen_index = raw_input("Select option: ")

    # Check if input is a number
    try:
        # It is a number, do whatever you want to do
        chosen_index = int(chosen_index)
        print "Info: %s\n" % product_list[chosen_index][3]
    except ValueError:
        # It's not a number, is the exit command?
        if chosen_index.lower() == "exit":
            print "Exiting.."
            sys.exit()

        # It's not the exit command, give an error message
        print "ERROR: Invalid option. Please provide a number\n"
        continue
```

**EDIT:** Python3 code:

```
import sys

product_list = [
    ["Mac Book Air","Apple","Laptop","Equipped with the new fifth-generation Intel Core i5 and i7 processors with Intel HD Graphics.",1350.5],
    ["Aspire SW5-111", "Acer", "Laptop", "Intel® Atom Z3745 processor Quad-core 1.33 GHz CPU.", 510],
    ["MeMo Pad 7", "Asus", "Tablet", "The 7 inch ASUS MeMO Pad 7 was created for those looking for a value tablet.", 620],
    ["Tab S8.4", "Samsung", "Tablet", "You will be surprised by the slim and sleek design of the GALAXY Tab S (8.4\") LTE. It only weighs 298g (LTE) and is easy to carry anywhere.", 788.5],
    ["iPhone 7", "Apple", "Phone", "The iPhone 7 is an exceptional phone in nearly every way.", 900],
    ["Galaxy S8", "Samsung", "Phone", "Newly released!", 1000]
]

# Loop until user says "exit"
while True:
    # Print list of options
    for product_index in range(len(product_list)):
        print("%x: %s %s" % (product_index, product_list[product_index][1], product_list[product_index][0]))

    # Read keyboard input from user
    chosen_index = input("Select option: ")

    # Check if input is a number
    try:
        # It is a number, do whatever you want to do
        chosen_index = int(chosen_index)
        print("Info: %s\n" % product_list[chosen_index][3])
    except ValueError:
        # It's not a number, is the exit command?
        if chosen_index.lower() == "exit":
            print("Exiting..")
            sys.exit()

        # It's not the exit command, give an error message
        print("ERROR: Invalid option. Please provide a number\n")
        continue
```

Comment: I tried running the code but i encounter an error that the raw_input is not define. may i know how should i define this? could you be kind to also provide me the code to list the item base on the selection? for instance, if the user select "1" from the option, the system will then list out the detail (as per the product_list) accordingly by Name:, Brand:, Category:, Description: Price:.

Comment: You're probably using python 3, this code is written in python 2. Just change `raw_input()` to `input()` and wrap the print-statements in parentheses, i.e. change wherever it says `print "something"` to `print("something")`. I'll leave the printing of the remaining info for you to figure out, it's good with some practice :)

Comment: @j.koo See my updated answer for a python3 implementation.

Comment: by the way, how should i quote it if i want to start the menu from 1 instead of 0?

Comment: Just add 1 to the `product_index`in the print-function like so: `print("%x: %s %s" % (product_index + 1, product_list[product_index][1], product_list[product_index][0]))`. Note that the actual indexes do not change, so users will type 1 when they want to access index 0, so you'll need to subtract 1 from the chosen index: `chosen_index = int(chosen_index) - 1`. By the way, please accept my answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Python 3

def main_menu():
    listOfProducts = [["Mac Book Air","Apple","Laptop","Equipped with the new fifth-generation Intel Core i5 and i7 processors with Intel HD Graphics.",1350.5],
        ["Aspire SW5-111", "Acer", "Laptop", "Intel® Atom Z3745 processor Quad-core 1.33 GHz CPU.", 510],
        ["MeMo Pad 7", "Asus", "Tablet", "The 7 inch ASUS MeMO Pad 7 was created for those looking for a value tablet.", 620],
        ["Tab S8.4", "Samsung", "Tablet", "You will be surprised by the slim and sleek design of the GALAXY Tab S (8.4\") LTE. It only weighs 298g (LTE) and is easy to carry anywhere.", 788.5],
        ["iPhone 7", "Apple", "Phone", "The iPhone 7 is an exceptional phone in nearly every way.", 900],
        ["Galaxy S8", "Samsung", "Phone", "Newly released!", 1000]]

    nr = 1
    for s in listOfProducts:
        print('%d. %s %s' % (nr, s[1], s[0]))
        nr += 1
    return input('\nEnter M to return to Main Menu Else please enter your selection: ')

print(main_menu())
```